# UI Test to check if an item exists is not working in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, ui-testing

I've looked through a dozen of different tutorials, articles etc., but nothing seems to be working for me. I'm attaching the code of an easy UI test in Swift to see if a section of a drawer exists. Any ideas why my test fails (not because I found a bug, but because my UI test is written incorrectly)? Thanks!

```
import XCTest
var app: XCUIApplication!


class MyAppUITests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false
        app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launchArguments.append("--uitesting")
        app.launch()
    }

    func testDrawerDisplaysPrivacyAgreement() {   app.navigationBars["MyApp.MainView"].buttons["burgerButton"].tap()

        XCTAssertTrue(app.tables.staticTexts["Privacy Policy"].exists)


    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem.

What I've done:

- I deleted the old version of MyAppUITests.
- From now on I add `let app = XCUIApplication(); app.launch()` every time I create a test.

The test below passes successfully! That works perfectly for me. :)

```
import XCTest
var app: XCUIApplication!


class MyAppUITests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        continueAfterFailure = false
    // Delete these. Doesn't work if put here and not in each test
    //    app = XCUIApplication()
    //    app.launchArguments.append("--uitesting")
    //    app.launch()
    }

    func testDrawerDisplaysPrivacyAgreement() {   
//  ** These two should be written in each test 
// **
        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.launch()
// **

       let burgerButtonMenu =         app.navigationBars["MyApp.MainView"].buttons["burgerButton"]
        burgerButtonMenu.tap()
        let privacy = app.tables.staticTexts["Privacy Policy"]

        if  burgerButtonMenu.isEnabled && burgerButtonMenu.isSelected {
            XCTAssertTrue(privacy.exists)


    }

    override func tearDown() {
        super.tearDown()
    }
}
```